# Spring Boot SSL Client

Tags: spring, rest, ssl, spring-boot, ssl-certificate

I am new to Spring Boot.  So far I am enjoying it.  I have developed a demo SSL rest web server that correctly handles mutual X.509 certificate authentication.  Using an IE browser with self signed client & server certificates, I have tested that the demo rest web server is working correctly -- both the server and browser are successfully exchanging and validating each others certificates.

I am having trouble finding an SSL client example that shows how to include the client certificate and issue the https.  Anybody have a simple rest client example that shows how to consume my ssl server?

Best Regards,
Steve Mansfield

Comment: What client do you have in mind? Java (with Spring)? Or something different?

Comment: Spring would be best but Java is ok as well.

Comment: Hi Steve, i stumbled on this question and wondering why the need to include SSL client code?

Comment: may not answer your question, but I started using OkHttp client, and it works just like standard java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could not get the above client submitted by Andy to work.  I kept getting errors saying that "localhost != clientname".  Anyways, I got this to work correctly.

```
 import java.io.IOException;

 import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
 import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException;
 import org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI;
 import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;

 public class SSLClient {

      static
        {
          System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","c:/apachekeys/client1.jks");
          System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");
          System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "c:/apachekeys/client1.jks");
          System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
       }

     public static void main(String[] args) throws HttpException, IOException {

         HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
         GetMethod method = new GetMethod();
         method.setURI(new URI("https://localhost:8443/restserver", false));
         client.executeMethod(method);

         System.out.println(method.getResponseBodyAsString());

     }

 }
```

Comment: this is system wide, it applies even to jdbc connections, not recommended

Comment: this is useful when your server needs client authentication using digital certificate .

Answer (score 20):

Given that you're using Spring, here's an example that shows how to use Spring's `RestTemplate` and Apache's `HttpClient` configured with a client certificate and to trust a self-signed certificate from the server:

```java
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(new File("keystore.jks")),
        "secret".toCharArray());
SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
        new SSLContextBuilder()
                .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, "password".toCharArray()).build());
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();
ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
        httpClient);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(
        "https://localhost:8443", String.class);
```

Comment: Another question about the code.  you have "secret" in keystore then "password" in loadkeymaterial.  What is secret?

Comment: I don't think there's anything to fix for `SSLConnectionSocketFactory`. Here's its [javadoc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLConnectionSocketFactory.html) if that helps. `secret` is the password for the entire key store. `password` is the password for the key in the key store.

Comment: Thanks Andy...I found the problem and I am working through it.  For some reason spring boot did not download the necessary jars.  Working to find them now.  Should have something working first thing tomorrow.

Comment: Found the problem with the compile.  I was using a down level version of sslconnectionsocketfactory.  Everything now compiles.  When I run the program I get -- Error = org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://localhost:8443/restserver":hostname in certificate didn't match: <localhost> != <aws server>; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <localhost> != <aws server>.  I have a POJO client that correctly authenticates against the server so I am pretty sure the server is working correctly.

Comment: It is two way ssl connection, doesn't it? I guess keyStore shouldn't be need with one way ssl connection. I mean only should be used trustStore

Comment: Any update how to set ssl with WebClient (webflux) ?

Comment: how can we use spring basic auth with this setup?

Answer (score 18):

The example of [user1707141](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1707141/user1707141) didn´t work for me and [skmansfield](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2808834/skmansfield) seems rather depending on specific files, that aren´t convention with Spring Boot / Maven. Also [Andy Wilkinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384297/andy-wilkinson)´s answer uses the constructor SSLConnectionSocketFactory, which was deprecated in Apache httpclient 4.4+ and also seems quite complex.

So I created a example project that should show everything *100% comprehensible* here: https://github.com/jonashackt/spring-boot-rest-clientcertificate

Besides the normal usage of the RestTemplate with `@Autowired` in your Testclass, be sure to configure your RestTemplate like this:

```
package de.jonashackt.restexamples;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;

@Configuration
public class RestClientCertTestConfiguration {

    private String allPassword = "allpassword";

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) throws Exception {

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder
                .create()
                .loadKeyMaterial(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:keystore.jks"), allPassword.toCharArray(), allPassword.toCharArray())
                .loadTrustMaterial(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:truststore.jks"), allPassword.toCharArray())
                .build();

        HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLContext(sslContext)
                .build();

        return builder
                .requestFactory(() -> new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: could not autowire,no beans of "RestTemplateBuilder " type found

Comment: 袁文涛, then you might didn't include `spring-boot-starter-web` or don`t yet use Spring Boot at all?

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late, but here is the code that works for me.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
            makeWebServiceCall();
    }
    
    public static void makeWebServiceCall() {
        TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;

        SSLContext sslContext;
        ResponseEntity<String> response = null;
        try {
            sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
                    .build();

            SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(csf).build();

            HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();

            requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
            
            StringBuffer plainCreds = new StringBuffer();
            plainCreds.append("username");
            plainCreds.append(":");
            plainCreds.append("password");
            byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.toString().getBytes();
            byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(plainCredsBytes);
            String userBase64Credentials = new String(base64CredsBytes);
            

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + userBase64Credentials);
            headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

            HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

            String url = "https:restUrl";
            
            response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
            
            if(response.getStatusCodeValue() == 200) {
                log.info("Success! Further processing based on the need");
            } else {
                log.info("****************Status code received: " + response.getStatusCodeValue() + ".************************");
            }

        } catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException e) {
            log.error("Exception occured. Here are the exception details: ", e);
        } catch(HttpClientErrorException e) {
            if(e.getRawStatusCode() == 403) {
                log.info("****************Status code received: " + e.getRawStatusCode() + ". You do not have access to the requested resource.************************");
                
            } else if(e.getRawStatusCode() == 404) {
                log.info("****************Status code received: " + e.getRawStatusCode() + ". Resource does not exist(or) the service is not up.************************");

            } else if(e.getRawStatusCode() == 400) {
                log.info("****************Status code received: " + e.getRawStatusCode() + ". Bad Request.************************");

            } else {
                log.info("****************Status code received: " + e.getRawStatusCode() + ".************************");
                
            }

           log.info("****************Response body: " + e.getResponseBodyAsString() + "************************");
        }
    }
 }
```

Here is the maven filed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-consuming-rest</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.3</version>
</dependency>

        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.6</version>
</dependency>
    
    
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way to do this. Inject the values for keyStoreLocation and keyStorePassword

```
@Configuration
public class SampleSSLClient extends RestTemplate{

    /** The key store password. */
    private  String keyStorePassword;
  
    /** The key store location. */
    private  String keyStoreLocation;
  
    /** The rest template. */
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
     /** The http components client http request factory. */
    private HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new custom rest template.
     */
    public CustomRestTemplate() {
        super();
    }
    
    public CustomRestTemplate(RestTemplate restTemplate){
        this.restTemplate = getRestTemplate();
    }
        
    /**
     * Rest template.
     *
     * @return the rest template
     */
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate()  {
        if (null == httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) {
            httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory = loadCert();
            restTemplate.setRequestFactory(httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory);
        }
        return restTemplate;
    }

    /**
     * Load cert.
     *
     * @return the http components client http request factory
     */
    private HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory loadCert()  {
        try {
            char[] keypass = keyStorePassword.toCharArray();
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create()
                    .loadKeyMaterial(getkeyStore(keyStoreLocation, keypass), keypass)
                    .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build();
            HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).build();
            httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
            httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(30000);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error(MessageFormat.format("Some Error", ex.getMessage()), ex);
            
        }
        return httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
    }

     /**
     * Key store.
     *
     * @param storePath the store path
     * @param password the password
     * @return the key store
     */
    private KeyStore getkeyStore(String storePath, char[] password) {
        KeyStore keyStore;
        try {
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            File key = ResourceUtils.getFile(storePath);
            try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(key)) {
                keyStore.load(in, password);
            }
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error(MessageFormat.format("Some Error", ex.getMessage()), ex);
        
        }
        return keyStore;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the key store password.
     *
     * @param keyStorePassword the new key store password
     */
    public void setKeyStorePassword(String keyStorePassword) {
        this.keyStorePassword = keyStorePassword;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the key store location.
     *
     * @param keyStoreLocation the new key store location
     */
    public void setKeyStoreLocation(String keyStoreLocation) {
        this.keyStoreLocation = keyStoreLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the rest template.
     *
     * @param restTemplate the new rest template
     */
    public void setRestTemplate(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Swallowing exceptions is not the best idea.

Comment: That’s called “handling expecting” @jannis

Answer (score -3):

This worked for me :

```
TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
javax.net.ssl.SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom()
        .loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();
SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(csf).build();
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```