# Spring boot two way SSL implementation

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am setting up two way SSL certificate for my spring boot application. I am using an already existing SSL certificate in the server where I was able to verify the connectivity with the upstream clients accessing my application.

My question is, if I need to implement any code changes to my spring boot application for my SSL security i.e. do I need to use `SSLContexts`, `SSLConnectionSocketFactory`? I was under the impression that I don't have to implement any code changes but I stumbled on this question: [Spring Boot SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770280/spring-boot-ssl-client).

Comment: What protocol are you using, https or raw sockets?

Comment: @SidMalani I am using HTTPS

Comment: Are you using self signed certs?

Comment: @SidMalani Nope

Comment: Then are they CA signed?