# Convert Curl Request in to java Rest Template Call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, ocsp

I have to make a OCSP cert verification call with the cert issued by some system . The OCSP team shared the below curl url as sample

```
curl --cert <XYZ>.pem.txt --key <XYZprivatekey>.key.pem --cacert ABCASDStaging.cer.txt https://osd.staging.sd.sd.sg --data-binary @request.der --header "Content-Type:application/ocsp-requests" --header "Host:ocsp.staging.xvc.sdf.sg" --output asdasd-ocsp-resp.der --insecure -v >> STG CDNS.txt2>&1
```

Im trying to code the above curl request in to java rest template request but unable to proceed. Can help to convert this request in to java rest template

Created the header

```
 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "ocsp-requests");
    headers.add("Host", "ocsp.staging.xvc.sdf.sg");
```

Comment: Please show your work.

Comment: @rushi - not Sure how to proceed further or the right way to implement

Comment: Using PEM with RestTemplate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33497874/resttemplate-with-pem-certificate

Comment: The converter posted by [sai manoj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14554871/sai-manoj) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70347946/4494577) should get you started with the rest: https://reqbin.com/curl

Answer (score 0):

This url has how to make ssl request in Java spring boot using Rest Template: [Spring Boot SSL Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770280/spring-boot-ssl-client)

Using the below url we can convert curl request to java code directly:
https://reqbin.com/curl

Hope this references might be useful